# Why is TypeScript code not compatible any more after compiling to JavaScript?

Tags: typescript, compilation

I consider that `const greet = require('./greet');` is equivalent to `import greet from './greet';`.

So these two files should work together:

1. `greet.ts`:

   `` export default ({ name, age }) => `Name: ${name}, Age: ${age}`; ``
2. `test.js`:

   `const greet = require("./greet");
   greet({ name: 'Smith', age: 21 });`

But after compiling, `greet.ts` turns out to be:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
exports["default"] = (function (_a) {
    var name = _a.name, age = _a.age;
    return "Name: " + name + ", Age: " + age;
});
```

instead of:

```
module.exports = (function (_a) {
    var name = _a.name, age = _a.age;
    return "Name: " + name + ", Age: " + age;
});
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write `export default`, then you export the member using a `"default"` key. Here is how to import it with CommonJS:

```
// test.js
const greet = require("./greet").default;
greet({ name: 'Smith', age: 21 });
```

I suggest the article [ES6 In Depth: Modules](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/) from Mozilla:

> There’s nothing magic about a default export; it’s just like any other export, except it’s named `"default"`.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript compiler takes the --target as ES5 or ES6. This depends on the compiler options you have set for your TS.
The code will be always different on that basis and you cannot expect the similar JS to be turned out.

So what does TypeScript offer over ES2015?  I feel add the most value:

1. Type Aliases
2. Interfaces
3. Future ES2016+ features (such as
   Annotations/Decorators and async/await)

Comment: Isn't interfaces a part of types?

Comment: No, Since Types and interfaces help provide the tooling it needs to identify problems early as we type them. With these features our editors don’t have to guess whether we used a function properly or not. The information is readily available for the tool to raise a red flag to us so we can fix he issues right away. In some cases, these tools can also help recommend and refactor for us!

Comment: In other words _since **types** help provide the tooling..._; again, why is interfaces a separate item from types?

Comment: 1.you cannot use implements on an class with type alias if you use union operator within your type definition

2.declaration merging doesn’t work with type alias

ype aliases can act sort of like interfaces, however, there are 3 important differences ( union types, declaration merging)
use whatever suites you and your team, just be consistent.


always use interface for public API's definition when authoring a library or 3rd party ambient type definitions
consider using type for your React Component Props and State

Comment: So when you say _types_, you specifically mean type aliases and nothing more? Because something I've heard a number of times is that all the features of TypeScript fit into two categories -- type safety, and future-JS emulation; and I thought you were echoing this sentiment.

Comment: I would say as there is fundamental difference and the way you implement as per your requirement. Interface is more derived from Object oriented concepts so it might contradict at some instance with interfaces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171223/discussion-between-zev-spitz-and-sohan).